# How to run a websockets server along with a flask server that serves the HTML page?

Tags: flask, websocket, python-3.7

I have created a chat application using the [websockets](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html) library in Python. Currently, I am running the chat application as follows:

> **python server.py** --- to run the websockets server
>
> **python websockets_chat.py** --- websockets_chat.py starts a flask app to serve the HTML page

and everything is working fine.

At this point, I have the following questions:

1. Is there a way to run both these servers together, i.e. with a single command and not with 2 different commands?
2. How can I deploy this app to Heroku?

[Here](https://github.com/mihika09/Websockets-Chat) is a link to my code